# How to do full text search in Adobe AIR applications?

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, full-text-search, air

It seems that AIR doesn't come packaged with the powerful [FTS module](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) for Sqlite (its a hot [requested feature](http://ideas.adobe.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=9D564F43-979A-4E35-AA21-85A61B6AB8DE&idea_id=83953B0D-48A4-43D0-A3CB-E89F3DFE989C))

What are the some other alternatives I can use? I want to be able to do simple boolean and phrase queries. Support for stemming would be great but not required. I am targeting the mobile platforms.

So far I've thought of three options:

1. Write a simple inverted index and a scorer
2. Do search on server side (last resort b/c it messes up offline capability)
3. Somehow install FTS module with AIR. First indication from googling is that its not feasible (looks like loading of modules is disabled in air)

Are there other alternatives?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how much data are you intending on searching?

Comment: I would doubt you would have a lot of data stored on the device in the first place, so just a simple search algorithm should be more than enough.  Most apps out there does server side searching for anything mildly complex.

Comment: AFAIK FTS is meant to dig through large quantities of text, which is not the case here..

Comment: FTS is overkill for 1MB of data.  You could write a flat file parser for that little of data and it would churn results fast enough on a mobile CPU.  NOT that I am suggesting that, but LIKE / REGEXP should be more than sufficient.  Just write some simple stubs to convert english query into your REGEXP

Comment: the two issues are orthogonal. capabilities like scoring, phrase searches with proximity, stemming, fuzzy searches are useful even for a small datasets.

Comment: How does FTS provide fuzzy look-up in sqlite? Link?

Comment: @lamalama, why are you arguing?  This is a limitation on SQLite for Air and nothing can be done about it. You are not google, you don't need those features for 1 meg of data. I'll vote to close if you can't accept that.

Comment: @sixfeesix sorry no fuzzy support.

Comment: @J_A_X before you get a power trip try looking at it this way - how are flex developers solving this problem when having FTS would be great idea. its a very simple question (if you move away from your false assumptions which btw are false - i'll leave that as an exercise for you)

Comment: Voted to close. User can't seem to understand there is a current limitation on the system for FTS.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do a simple regex search through the database on pertinent tables/columns and then sort accordingly (by date?).

Comment: sorting by date makes no sense for my case. regex would work for the simplest queries (1 term). if its more than one term, then it could ugly really quick

Comment: Why would it get ugly? `SELECT * FROM SOMETHING WHERE description REGEXP 'firstTerm|secondTerm';`

Comment: +1 - date inclusion does not preclude the validity of answer and answer is more than sufficient for 1MB of data.

Comment: If it's for any column, then search for all columns.  If you want to do a proximity search, split the query into individual words and rank the results by the occurrences.  The advanced features that you're asking for is not event included in SQLite FTS.  You're not google, you're just searching through a meg of data, which I've done before and it really isn't hard.  You're looking for an overly simple, overly advanced feature-set that you just won't find.

Comment: sorry but all your assumptions are wrong. 1) FTS is only useful for large datasets (omg google scale!!) 2) "split the query into individual words and rank the results by the occurrences". this is good old hand waving. maybe you should refresh or learn fundamentals of informational retrieval. 3) "advanced features that you're asking for is not event included in SQLite FTS"